# How can I find the mle of a ratio of parameters given their mles?

Tags: statistics, optimization, transformation, statistical-inference

I currently have a probability density with 2 parameter $\alpha $ and $\beta$. I've calculated $\hat{\alpha},\hat{\beta}$ aswell as the expected information $I_G$.

If I now want the MLE of $\gamma$ where $\gamma=\frac{\alpha}{\beta}$, would the in-variance property of MLE let me make the statement that $\hat{\gamma}=\frac{\hat{\alpha}}{\hat{\beta}}$

What would the asymptotic distribution of $\hat\gamma$ be? If It is an MLE it will be asymptotically normal with mean $\gamma_0$ but what sort of transformation could I apply to get the variance of $\hat\gamma$

Comment: What's your exact density?

Comment: p(y)=$\frac{\Gamma(y+\alpha)}{y!\Gamma(\alpha))}\frac{\beta^\alpha}{(1+\beta)^{y+\alpha}}$

Comment: If you asked [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2899758/how-can-i-find-the-mle-of-a-function-of-parameters) same question here using a different account, please be patient for receiving feedback.

Comment: In the form you have written the pmf, it looks like $Y$ is a [Gamma-Poisson mixture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution#Gamma%E2%80%93Poisson_mixture), so that $Y$ can be said to have a negative binomial distribution with pmf $$P(Y=y)=\binom{
\alpha+y-1}{y}\left(\frac{\beta}{1+\beta}\right)^{\alpha}\left(1-\frac{\beta}{1+\beta}\right)^y\mathbf1_{y\,\in\,\{0,1,\ldots\}}$$ with $$0<\frac{\beta}{1+\beta}<1,\text{ i.e. }\,\beta>0\quad\text{ and }\quad\alpha>0$$...

Comment: ...Also have a look at the MLE section of the linked wiki page. You cannot find the MLE of one of the parameters in negative binomial and gamma distributions in closed form (numerical solutions are possible). You might find something for the ratio of the MLEs though.
If $(\hat\alpha,\hat\beta)$ is the MLE of $(\alpha,\beta)$, then $f(\hat\alpha,\hat\beta)$ is the MLE of $f(\alpha,\beta)$. Think of $\theta=(\alpha,\beta)$ as a single (vector) parameter, so the invariance property holds.